# Rails: turbo-frame with src requested interpreted as format.html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hotwire-rails, turbo-frames

I've noticed this strange behavior of turbo frames loading lazily via `src` attribute setting:

```slim
nav
  = turbo_frame_tag 'primary_menu', src: primary_menu_path
```

```
  : def primary_menu
  :   respond_to do |format|
  :     format.turbo_stream
> :     format.html { binding.pry ; render plain: 'should not reach this block' }
  :   end
  : end

)> turbo_frame_request?
=> true
```

For some reason, it is interpreted as regular requested html request, although
`turbo_frame_request?` returns => `true`. What's causing it and how to fix it?

P.S. `primary_menu.turbo_stream.slim` exists for that controller action.

Local versions:

`hotwire-rails 0.1.3`
`@hotwired/turbo-rails 7.0.0-beta.5`

Answer (score 3):

Before someone with better knowledge of `turbo` internals explains it properly, below is a method that worked for me:

```erb
<%= turbo_frame_tag 'primary_menu', src: primary_menu_path %>
```

Would be interpreted as HTML request:

```ruby
def primary_menu
  # load your thing

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
  end
end
```

in your `primary_menu.html.erb` make sure you wrap your content with `<%= turbo_frame_tag 'primary_menu' do %>` block.

Keep in mind that:

- `turbo_frame_tag` names have to match here and its original definition/require.
- any additional `turbo_frame_tag` wrapped blocks in that response would be silently ignored.

Comment: I had the same problem with you, but I'm using link_to. I was expecting a request with format TURBO_STREAM, but it was sending with format HTML. I think this is the normal comportment for turbo when is a GET request.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior, as stated in [the Turbo docs](https://turbo.hotwired.dev/handbook/streams)

> By default, Turbo doesn’t add the text/vnd.turbo-stream.html MIME type when submitting links, or forms with a method type of GET

To override this behavior:

> To use Turbo Streams responses with GET requests in an application you can instruct Turbo to include the MIME type by adding a data-turbo-stream attribute to a link or form.

It is also answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75210863/6447634)

The reason for this is that for GET requests, it makes more sense to use a Turbo *frame* not *stream*