# turbo_frame_tag request with other formats than HTML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hotwire-rails, turbo

Given the following

```rb
<%= turbo_frame_tag dom_id(@item, "loader_helper"), src: home_index_path(@item) %>
```

This code will trigger with page load other request to specified controller

```
Started GET "/home/1" for ::1 at 2023-01-23 16:10:39 +0300
Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
```

The problem is that I want to render not HTML, but rather turbo_stream format with some page modifications and don't rely on some JS solution.

So I would expect the following pseudocode to work

```rb
<%= turbo_frame_tag dom_id(@item, "loader_helper"), src: home_index_path(@item), format: :turbo_stream %>
```

to load action like so

```
Started GET "/home/1" for ::1 at 2023-01-23 16:10:39 +0300
Processing by HomeController#index as TURBO_STREAM
```

and then in controller I can handle it with specific formats

```rb
..
def index
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.turbo_stream
  end
end
```

Are there any workarounds? Or this is intended by design, so we won't be able to trigger turbo_stream on page load (you can do it with js easily), and manipulate with some HTML.

Comment: My two cents: would the format not be part of the url, rather than an option to the turbo frame tag, like this: `my_path(whatever, format: turbo_stream)`. Also there is a specific data attribute if you want to trigger turbo stream with GET methods : `data-turbo-stream="true"` . Though not sure it can be appended to a turbo frame.

Comment: @Maxence, data-turbo-stream didn't work, however moving format to part of url so `src: home_path(item, format: :turbo_stream)` did work expected way. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the doc https://turbo.hotwired.dev/handbook/streams
it injects `text/vnd.turbo-stream.html` for POST, PUT, PATCH, or DELETE HTTP method.
If you want to use it for the GET method, you must add the `data-turbo-stream` attribute.
So for your case, you can try the following code:

```
<%= turbo_frame_tag dom_id(@item, "loader_helper"), src: home_index_path(@item, format: :turbo_stream) %>
```

Reference: https://github.com/hotwired/turbo-site/pull/40#discussion_r570471371

Comment: Processing by HomeController#index as HTML. Unfortunately this one not working. However modifying url directly with `format: :turbo_stream` does.

Comment: ok I just updated my comment according to your finding

Comment: drop `data: { 'turbo-stream' => true }` it has no effect, and I will accept answer

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the question and the answer. I got it working too for my use case with the following code:

The view file, containing the turbo frame and requesting the index action of the `Calculators` controller:

```
<%= turbo_frame_tag :calculator, src: calculators_path(format: :turbo_stream) do %>
   <!-- some initial HTML content -->
<% end %>
```

The `Calculators` controller and its `index` action:

```
def index
  respond_to do |format|
    format.turbo_stream
  end
end
```

The turbo stream file `index.turbo_stream.erb` rendering the partial `_new.html.erb`:

```
<%= turbo_stream.update "calculator", partial: "calculators/new" %>
```